# setTimeout giving unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript

So I have this code that I am running inside of the google chrome console, and every time that I try to run it it give me unexpected identifier on line: 12. I went to that line and it is the setTimeout. I really don't know how to fix this, I tried to just call snipebot() but that didn't work either.

```
function snipebot(itemID, max_price){
    var ItemURL = "http://www.roblox.com/Item.aspx?id=" + itemID;
            $.get(ItemURL, function(data){
                var purchaseData = $($(data).find(".PurchaseButton")[0]).data();
                        if (purchaseData['expectedPrice'] <= max_price){
                            $.post('/API/Item.ashx?rqtype=purchase&productID=' + purchaseData['productId'] + '&expectedCurrency=1&expectedPrice=' + purchaseData['expectedPrice'] + '&expectedSellerId=' + purchaseData['expectedSellerId'] + '&userAssetID=' + purchaseData['userassetId'], function(){
                            console.log('[' + purchaseData['expectedPrice'] + ']');
                            });
                        }
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
            snipebot(itemID, max_price);
            });
};
snipebot(18426536, 140);
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add the time interval for your setTimeout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unexpected because your call to `$.get` hasn't been closed properly on the previous line:

```
function snipebot(itemID, max_price){
    var ItemURL = "http://www.roblox.com/Item.aspx?id=" + itemID;
            $.get(ItemURL, function(data){
                var purchaseData = $($(data).find(".PurchaseButton")[0]).data();
                        if (purchaseData['expectedPrice'] <= max_price){
                            $.post('/API/Item.ashx?rqtype=purchase&productID=' + purchaseData['productId'] + '&expectedCurrency=1&expectedPrice=' + purchaseData['expectedPrice'] + '&expectedSellerId=' + purchaseData['expectedSellerId'] + '&userAssetID=' + purchaseData['userassetId'], function(){
                            console.log('[' + purchaseData['expectedPrice'] + ']');
                            });
                        }
            }); // <-- here
            setTimeout(function(){
            snipebot(itemID, max_price);
            }, 2000); // <!-- See below
};
snipebot(18426536, 140);
```

Also note my second comment, where you've missed the 2nd parameter to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), namely how long to delay for.  I've added in a two second delay as an example.  Without this, it defaults to 0, which may or may not be what you intended.